# JavaScript alert not showing up in the browser page but at the right hand side of screen

Tags: javascript

Visual Studio Code must have had an update. I wasn't able to find anything on their website but I wasn't seeing my alert I created like it used to appear on the browser page and then I noticed that the alert is at the bottom right hand of the screen outside of the browser page but inside the Visual Studio Code. Is there any way to make this show up in the browser preview using extension for Live Server?[See attached screen shot - scroll to the bottom right to see the alert.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS6Mh.jpg)

Comment: If someone came to you asking for help, showed you a picture of the problem, and the only other thing they said was "oh, it's using javascript", would you be able to help them?  Or would you ask for more information?  Please review [ask] to learn more about making questions that StackOverflow users are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a VSCode runtime and VSCode alerts look just like that. If you run it in an actual browser it will give you a browser alert as you are used to.